# implementing a photo browser view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mwphotobrowser

I'm looking for a good photo browser controller that will browse photos, will support zooming and rotation.
I found `mwphotoviewer` which seems to be the popular option, and its indeed very good. but is there any way to use it in as a tab in a `tabbarviewcontroller` and not as to push it from a `navigationviewcontroller`?

so far in every project that I have seen, they use either a

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
```

I just want it to be there,

any ideas?

Comment: `[self.tabBarViewController setViewControllers:@[someView, photoViewer]];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self addChildViewController:self.browser];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.browser view]];
[self.browser didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

solved it for me.

Comment: Did you have any issues with rotation when you add browser with this way? I did it but when i rotate the device a part of my screen seems to be dead. No touch events recognized if width is bigger than 320 width in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UINavigationController` you can use `UITabBarController` and set it view controller as the one one in which you are supposed to browse the photos.

Comment: yeah, I tried that. I just used the storyboard and put a view controller that is a mwphotobrowser, but its just presenting a black screen.

Comment: You cannot add only one controller to it, it accepts an array of view controllers. See apple documentations for more details

Comment: is solved it like this : [self addChildViewController:self.browser];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.browser view]];
    [self.browser didMoveToParentViewController:self]; but I don't want to accept it because it seems pretty hack. and there are more problems to solve like displaying the toolbar and caption above the tabbar

Comment: If you are using toolbar also then I would suggest you to go with the Navigation controller only as it will populate the bottom of the screen. and apple discourages it.

Comment: Yeah, I will consider my UI some more. Anyways about the question, I feel its solved and while the MWPhotoBrowser is not very customisable, his code is clear enough to do whatever you need to its looks alone.